# Is the Residue Theorem always better than Cauchy Integral Theorem for finding intergrals?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the course of complex analysis Cachy Integral Formula comes before the Residue Theorem. Both the proof of the Residue Theorem ( https://math.berkeley.edu/~dcorwin/math185/residuethm.pdf ) and the proof of the Cauchy Integral Formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Proof_sketch ) are based on the Cauchy Integral Theorem and the fact that $\int_C{\frac{1}{z-a}}=2\pi i$, where C is a curve bounding a disk on the complex plane. As far as i understood, neither does the Residue Theorem explicitly rely on the Cauchy Integral Formula, neither does the Cauchy Integral Formula explicitly rely on the Residue Theorem.

But, in the course, after proving the Cauchy Integral Formula, some tasks are given where it is needed to find an integral of a function with one or more poles, and it is done by multiplying that function $f(z)$ so that it no longer has a singularity at a point, then dividing that new function $f_1(z)$ by the term we multiplied the original function by so that we can apply the CIF for this function $f_1(z)$ ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Example ) . This approach seems very artificial when we already know the Residue Theorem, because it can help us calculate the integral of $f(z)$ right away.

So, my question is - why ever calculate integrals using the Cauchy Integral Formula, considering CIF and the Residue Theorem are equally far away from the beginning in the course of complex analysis (or at least it seems like that to me)?

Comment: You may use the Cauchy Integral Theorem for things other than computing integrals.  A few examples are on the page you quoted ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: The Cauchy integral formula and the residue theorem are almost trivial consequences of the Cauchy integral theorem, you should not make a strong difference between them. What is strange is that together with that bounded entire functions are constant this makes a very powerful framework to deal with integrals, generating functions, series, Fourier transforms.